Is it possible to create a route between two existing Docker Networks?
I have two groups of containers. Each group is defined by a docker-compose.yml, and each group has an associated network such that all containers defined in the same docker-compose.yml file can all talk to each other.
However, the containers from one group cannot talk to the other group.
Both networks are using the bridge driver. I am assuming that these two groups of containers are not supposed to be able to talk to each other, however I do not know enough about Docker to be able to say with certainty.
Assuming this is the expected behavior, is it possible to provide a mechanism to connect the two Docker networks together such that a container on one of the two networks can talk to a container on the other?

It can be done using an "external network"
Important to note: This appears to be a bi-directional thing. It doesn't seem to matter which of the two docker-compose.yml file it is defined in. This is important because more than likely you are in the same situation as myself where you have one existing system, and you are trying to connect a second system to the existing network
Here are the details of how to implement it:

Assume from the first docker-compose.yml file, a network has been created. It might be explicitly defined, or it might have a default name. In my case, this was network_default

In the second docker-compose.yml explicitly define the following sections:
services:
  <name>:
    image: ...
    container_name: ...
    networks:
      - default_network_for_this_container
      - additional_proxy_network
    ports:
      - <existing port definitions>
    environment:
      ...

networks:
  default_network_for_this_container:
    name: <network name>
  additional_proxy_network:
    name: network_default
    external: true

The key parts are:

an additional "proxy" network, with external: true set
keep your existing network configuration
important! note the network name network_default used by the additional proxy network. This must be the same name as the existing network name created by the first docker-compose.yml file




I don't think "proxy" is correct term. https://docs.docker.com/compose/how-tos/networking/
